# iOS why i am not able to create child directories within parent directory within the Documents directory?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

i'm facing issues while creating child directories within the Documents dir

i get Documents path with NSHomeDirectory()
return: **/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3CE312DC-8A49-4EF6-83D1-C205F2EF1C0B**

and create dir with

`std::filesystem::create_directory((homePath+"/Documents/assets").c_str())` return **success**

`std::filesystem::create_directory((homePath+"/Documents/assets/images").c_str())` return **permission denied**

and with NSFileManager return the same

```
void iOSCreateDirectory(const char*path){
 NSString*directory=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:path];
 NSError*err;
 NSFileManager*fm=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
 if(![fm fileExistsAtPath:directory]){
  if(![fm createDirectoryAtPath:directory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&err]){
   NSLog(@"CreateDirectory Error %@ %@", directory, err);
  }
 }
}
```

`iOSCreateDirectory((homePath+"/Documents/assets").c_str())` return **success**

`iOSCreateDirectory((homePath+"/Documents/assets/images").c_str())` return **Code=13 "permission denied"**

**Error Code=513 "You don't have permission to save the file "images" in the folder "assets"."**

am i missing something here?

**Solved**

the problem is the assets directory was created with std::filesystem::create_directory()

Thanks

Comment: Hi, any more details how you test your code? You run on jailbroken device? You run code as a root or user? (Minh? :))

Comment: i run on non-jailbroken device 15.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it may be a formatting issue with your path construction. This works:

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *appDirURL = [[fm URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSError *error;
NSURL *newDirectoryURL = [[appDirURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"assets"] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"images"];
if (![fm createDirectoryAtURL:newDirectoryURL withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: thanks. i found the problem is the "assets" directory was created with std::filesystem::create_directory() it cause some permission issues so i removed the app and now createDirectoryAtPath() works

Comment: @0x4d696e68 Great to hear - would you please give my answer a tick or upvote?